# Boost Lambda/Phoenix - how to do lambda which returns another lambda?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, functional-programming, currying

Does Boost Lambda/Phoenix supports out of box something like lambda which returns another lambda?

For instance, that can be used to do some kind of currying:

```
std::cout << [](int x){return [=](int y){return x+y;};}(1)(2);
```

How to achieve similar purpose with Boost Lambda/Phoenix (+ as a bonus - we would get polymorphic behaviour)?

Comment: The problem I had in trying to answer this is that `arg1` gets consumed by the outermost `bind` -- I want an `arg1` I can pass to the inner `bind`, but the outer `bind` eats it instead.  If I had a way to "escape" the argument placeholder...

Comment: @Yakk, you could try to use boost::bind - AFAIK it differs from lambda/phoenix bind ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lambda/s08.html#idp111396608 ). Also, post code of your try as answer - bounty ends tomorrow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Boost Phoenix Scope: let/lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/scope.html)

[Live demo:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3095834f635c3b5c)

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace phoenix;
using namespace arg_names;
using namespace local_names;

int main()
{
   // capture by reference:
   cout <<
      (lambda(_a=_1)[_1 + _a ])(1)(2)
   << endl;
   cout <<
      (lambda(_b=_1)[lambda(_a=_1)[_1 + _a + _b ]])(1)(2)(3)
   << endl;
   // capture by value:
   cout <<
      (lambda(_a=val(_1))[_1 + _a ])(1)(2)
   << endl;
   cout <<
      (lambda(_b=val(_1))[lambda(_a=val(_1))[_1 + _a + _b ]])(1)(2)(3)
   << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
3
6
3
6
```

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk is there an easy way to generate a lazy evaluation, like `[&]()->void{ fully_bound_expression_that_does_not_run_until_later; }`?

Comment: @Yakk, Could you please describe in details what do you mean (maybe via full example with C++11 lambdas)? Do you mean http://liveworkspace.org/code/30jCv6$0 ? Or maybe http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Kon3g$0 ?

Comment: `void some_function(int x); auto lazy_do_on_x = [](int x){return [=]{some_function(x);};}; auto lazy_do = lazy_do_on_x(5); lazy_do();` -- when I naively try to use `bind`, when every argument is bound, it evaluates the expression.  Instead, I want to `bind` lazily, so the final execution only happens after I evaluate (using `()`) the nullary result of the `bind`.

Comment: @Yakk, std::bind does return nullary function: auto lazy=bind(some_function,11); lazy(); http://liveworkspace.org/code/2BLbzn$0